# Angle in Rodrigues' rotation formula

Tags: rotations, cross-product, angle

In https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rodrigues%27_rotation_formula

it distinguishes angles $\theta$ and $\alpha$ and says "the two angles $\theta$ and $\alpha$  are not necessarily equal"

To my knowledge, I think they should be same. When we use dot product and cross product, we use the same angle, that is the angle between two vectors. Why are they not the same?

[image]

Comment: [Welcome to Math.SE!](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/4928/290189) Please use MathJax.
For some basic information about writing math at this site see e.g. [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation),
[mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020),
[main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559)
and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Comment: @GNUSupporter Thanks, I change it to MathJax

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What they mean is that the axis of rotation $\hat{\bf k}$ can be obtained via the product of two other vector ${\bf a}$ and ${\bf b}$

$$
\hat{\bf k} = \frac{{\bf a}\times {\bf b}}{|{\bf a}\times {\bf b}|}
$$

it just happens that the angle between these two vectors is $\alpha$

[image]

Comment: I got it. Thank you very much.